# Purpose of high stratum values for the local clock (fudge option)

Tags: ntp

In the NTP configuration, what is the purpose of specifying **high** stratum values for the local clock?

```
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```

Correct me if I'm wrong: the server will rely anyway on the internal clock if remote NTP servers (which have low stratum e.g. 2 or 3) are unreachable. Otherwise, it will sync time with these NTP servers.

Therefore, is the above config line unnecessary, and setting a local clock stratum makes sense only if that stratum value is **lower** than some of the remote NTP servers stratum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high stratum means a lower priority clock. NTP clients often have an odd number of servers, but more than one, and the reason for using a high stratum for a local clock is to advise clients that this clock should be less trusted than other clocks synchronised to a better source.

You also asked whether this was the default, even without the `fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10` configuration statement.

By default the `ntpd` implementation of an NTP server won't synchronise to a local clock at all, so it won't serve time. (I'm not as familiar with other NTP implementations, so I can't comment on those.) Adding the `fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10` line allows it to consider continuing to serve time from the local clock (at the really low priority stratum 10) when all other sources have failed. This is generally a better scenario for a time-sensitive environment (e.g. one using Kerberos or other time-based authentication) than letting all the end client systems freewheel without synchronisation.